How can I fix the large blank space appearing below my ScrollView in a React Native chat search screen?
I'm experiencing an issue in my React Native app where there's a large amount of blank space below my ScrollView. I'm using a combination of ScrollView and FlatList to display users and recent user data on a chat search screen. However, this undesired extra space appears below the ScrollView, and I can't seem to figure out why.
Here is the relevant portion of the code
import React, { useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, TextInput, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { debounce } from 'lodash';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import SkeletonLoader from '../components/SkeletonLoader';

const dummyUsers = [
 
];

const recentUsers = [
 
];


const TabButton = React.memo(({ title, isActive, onPress }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity 
    style={[styles.tabButton, isActive && styles.activeTabButton]} 
    onPress={onPress}
  >
    <Text style={[styles.tabButtonText, isActive && styles.activeTabButtonText]}>{title}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
));

const UserItem = React.memo(({ item, onPress }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity 
    style={styles.item} 
    onPress={() => onPress(item)}
    accessible={true}
    accessibilityLabel={`${item.name}, ${item.type}`}
    accessibilityHint={`Tap to view ${item.name}'s profile`}
  >
    {item.profilePic ? (
      <Image source={{ uri: item.profilePic }} style={styles.profilePic} />
    ) : (
      <View style={[styles.profilePic, styles.profilePicPlaceholder]}>
        <Text style={styles.profilePicPlaceholderText}>{item.name[0]}</Text>
      </View>
    )}
    <View style={styles.userInfo}>
      <Text style={styles.userName}>{item.name}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.userType}>{item.type}</Text>
    </View>
    {item.unreadCount > 0 && (
      <View style={styles.unreadBadge}>
        <Text style={styles.unreadBadgeText}>{item.unreadCount}</Text>
      </View>
    )}
  </TouchableOpacity>
));

const RecentUserItem = React.memo(({ item, onPress }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(item)} style={styles.recentUserItem}>
    <Image source={{ uri: item.profilePic }} style={styles.recentUserPic} />
    <Text style={styles.recentUserName}>{item.name}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
));

export default function SearchScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [filteredUsers, setFilteredUsers] = useState(dummyUsers);
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('Chats');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const searchInputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleCancel = useCallback(() => {
    navigation.goBack();
  }, [navigation]);

  const debouncedSearch = useCallback(
    debounce((text) => {
      setLoading(true);
      // Simulate API call
      setTimeout(() => {
        const filtered = dummyUsers.filter(user =>
          user.name.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())
        );
        setFilteredUsers(filtered);
        setLoading(false);
      }, 500);
    }, 300),
    []
  );

  const handleSearch = useCallback((text) => {
    setValue(text);
    if (text.trim() === '') {
      setFilteredUsers(dummyUsers);
    } else {
      debouncedSearch(text);
    }
  }, [debouncedSearch]);

  const handleItemPress = useCallback((item) => {
    alert(`Pressed ${item.type || 'User'}: ${item.name}`);
  }, []);

  const renderItem = useCallback(({ item }) => (
    <UserItem item={item} onPress={handleItemPress} />
  ), [handleItemPress]);

  const tabs = ['Chats', 'Channels', 'Media', 'Files', 'Links'];

  const ListEmptyComponent = useCallback(() => (
    <View style={styles.emptyContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.emptyText}>No results found</Text>
    </View>
  ), []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView  style={styles.container} >
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
          <Icon name="search" size={20} color="#999" style={styles.searchIcon} />
          <TextInput
            ref={searchInputRef}
            style={styles.searchInput}
            value={value}
            onChangeText={handleSearch}
            placeholder="Search"
            placeholderTextColor="#999"
          />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleCancel} style={styles.cancelButton}>
          <Text style={styles.cancelButtonText}>Cancel</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
        <FlatList
          data={tabs}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TabButton
              title={item}
              isActive={activeTab === item}
              onPress={() => setActiveTab(item)}
            />
          )}
          horizontal
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item}
        />
      </View>
      <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.recentUsersContainer} contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between', }}>
        
        {recentUsers.map(user => (
          <RecentUserItem key={user.id} item={user} onPress={handleItemPress} />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
      {loading ? (
        <SkeletonLoader />
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          data={filteredUsers}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          ListEmptyComponent={value.trim() !== '' ? ListEmptyComponent : null}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.listContent}
        />
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  header: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    paddingVertical: 8,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#e0e0e0',
    
  },
  searchContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  searchIcon: {
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  searchInput: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  cancelButton: {
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
  cancelButtonText: {
    color: '#007AFF',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  tabContainer: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#e0e0e0',
    
  },
  tabButton: {
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    paddingVertical: 12,
  },
  activeTabButton: {
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: '#007AFF',
  },
  tabButtonText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#999',
  },
  activeTabButtonText: {
    color: '#007AFF',
  },
  listContent: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    flex:0 
  },
  item: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingLeft: 16,
    paddingVertical: 16,
    
  },
  profilePic: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
    marginRight: 16,
  },
  profilePicPlaceholder: {
    backgroundColor: '#007AFF',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  profilePicPlaceholderText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  userInfo: {
    flex: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#e0e0e0',
    paddingBottom: 16,
    paddingRight: 16,
  },
  userName: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  userType: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#999',
  },
  unreadBadge: {
    backgroundColor: '#007AFF',
    borderRadius: 10,
    minWidth: 20,
    height: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    marginRight: 16,
  },
  unreadBadgeText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  emptyContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },
  emptyText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#999',
  },
  recentUsersContainer: {
    paddingVertical: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#e0e0e0',   
    flex:1 
  },
  recentUserItem: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 8,
    height: 15,

  },
  recentUserPic: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 30,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  recentUserName: {
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

Here is a screenshot, i made the color red so its easier to see

I tried:
contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between', }}"
On the ScrollView, it doesn't seem to fix it either.

This question is similar to: react native scrollView Height always stays static and does not change. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
